# Nextjs ReactServerComponentsError:

Tags: reactjs, loops, next.js

im new to nextjs
this is the first app building using Nextjs

i tried to add FAQ.js page but it fails

here is my code:

```
// ./src/app/services/Faq.js
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const FAQ = () => {
  const faqData = [
    {
      question: "What is outsourcing?",
      answer:
        "Our pricing is flexible and depends on the scope and complexity of your project. We offer competitive rates and can provide a detailed quote after discussing your requirements.",
    },
    {
      question: "What do I need to get started on my project?",
      answer:
        "You can reach our support team by emailing support@kargakarga.comment. We typically respond within 24 hours during business days.",
    },
    {
      question: "Why is it beneficial to outsource the art component?",
      answer:
        "Yes, we offer a 30-day money-back guarantee. If you're not satisfied with our services, please contact us for a refund.",
    },
  ];

  const [openQuestionIndex, setOpenQuestionIndex] = React.useState(-1);

  const toggleAnswer = (index) => {
    setOpenQuestionIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === index ? -1 : index));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="p-4">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-6">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
        <div className="space-y-4">
          {faqData.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="border rounded p-4 shadow-md">
              <div
                className="cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => toggleAnswer(index)}
              >
                <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold">{item.question}</h2>
              </div>
              {index === openQuestionIndex && (
                <p className="text-gray-600 mt-2">{item.answer}</p>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FAQ;
```

i entered in a loop i cant get out from it

whenever i tried usestate from react im getting this error

```
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

   ╭─[/Users/Documents/kargakarga-task/src/app/services/Faq.js:1:1]
 1 │ // ./src/app/services/Faq.js
 2 │ import React,{useState} from 'react';
   ·               ────────
 3 │ 
 4 │ const FAQ = () => {
 5 │   const faqData = [
   ╰────
```

i tried other ways but none of them worked

another exapmle

```
// ./src/app/services/Faq.js
import { defineComponent } from 'next/server';

const FAQ = defineComponent(() => {
  const faqData = [
    {
      question: "What is outsourcing?",
      answer:
        "Our pricing is flexible and depends on the scope and complexity of your project. We offer competitive rates and can provide a detailed quote after discussing your requirements.",
    },
    {
      question: "What do I need to get started on my project?",
      answer:
        "You can reach our support team by emailing support@kargakarga.comment. We typically respond within 24 hours during business days.",
    },
    {
      question: "Why is it beneficial to outsource the art component?",
      answer:
        "Yes, we offer a 30-day money-back guarantee. If you're not satisfied with our services, please contact us for a refund.",
    },
  ];

  const toggleAnswer = (index) => {
    // Implement your state management logic here
    // You can use Server Components' state management if needed
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="p-4">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-6">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
        <div className="space-y-4">
          {faqData.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="border rounded p-4 shadow-md">
              <div
                className="cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => toggleAnswer(index)}
              >
                <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold">{item.question}</h2>
              </div>
              {/* Implement the logic to display answers here */}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default FAQ;
```

i need help
anyone can get me out from this loop?

Comment: the answer was very easy all i had to do is to add //"use client" to the file

Answer (score 0):

the answer was very easy
all i had to do is to add this sentence to the child and parent component

```
 "use client"
```